# Why does my TypeScript report an error for a union type?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

I have:

```
type: 'WEBSOCKET' | 'HTTP_STREAM';
connection: WebSocketType | HTTPStreamType;
```

where:

```
interface Header {
  key: string;
  val: string;
}

export interface WebSocketType {
  websocketUrl: string;
}

export interface HTTPStreamType {
  streamUrl: string;
  method: 'get' | 'put';
  headers: Header[];
}
```

I'm trying:

```
        if (newStream.type === 'WEBSOCKET') {
          if (newStream?.connection?.websocketUrl?.length > 0) {
            return setIsNextDisabled(false)
          }
        }
```

but the error I get is:

```
Property 'websocketUrl' does not exist on type 'WebSocketType | HTTPStreamType'.
  Property 'websocketUrl' does not exist on type 'HTTPStreamType'.
```

I thought the `guard` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: You should give a complete (not) working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have something like:

```
interface MyData {
    type: 'WEBSOCKET' | 'HTTP_STREAM';
    connection: WebSocketType | HTTPStreamType;
}
```

According to this interface, you could have a `type` of `WEBSOCKET` and a `connection` of the `HTTPStreamType`. Nowhere have you guaranteed any linkage between members of each union. `type` and `connection` could both be either member of the union.

That is is why typescript doesn't think your guard has helped.

Instead, you want a different kind of union:

```
type MyData = {
    type: 'WEBSOCKET';
    connection: WebSocketType;
} | {
    type: 'HTTP_STREAM';
    connection: HTTPStreamType;
}
```

This type says that `MyData` could be a type `WEBSOCKET` with a `WebSocketType` connection, *or* it could be a type `HTTP_STREAM` with a `HTTPStreamType` connection. But it could never mix one property from the first, and another from the second.

Now typescript can infer that a a check against one of the properties allows the other property type to be known.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBITgE2sg3gKGWQGsIBPALmQGcwpQBzAbkOQDc4AbK2+kZ-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) with code that passes type checking.

---

With some refactoring you can avoid repeating common properties [like so](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBITgE2sg3gKGWQGsIBPALmQGcwpQBzAbkOQDc4AbK2+kZ-AF98+CAA8ADgHsoYZKEixEKAOoQARgGUpCUmAAqZCSgJEA7huo69AVSjcadRi2GjJMuQujwkaffoAFTToMAFtDYzxWXjC7B15nVlCIMAALKUwqAHIGFKzkAB9kLIkAVzAsliJUjGwoaip0LGgAbQBdFxEAei6AOn6RLyVfAFkyAGEpUNCpEAARODA4KKIiGCkpHid+ViJ1OCgqEFLQ9WghQfBvZWQ1LWsUhaXkcUgQTGpkMcnp2afl0yrMBGCDZFQAUQAQpoAPLjADS4P0WV2yAQsxAEAQYGAsyod20uhSEQgF3wQx8KFQYDAEmCUDC-xeYjeHy+EymM3miwBqOBxmyqH8AQA+pp9AAlcEAQRGlVR6JAmOxuJAjWF9LCJM6+H5KDGTIAvLcNIS9EyitTaZq4KF-vggA).

```
interface MyCommonData {
    foo: string
    bar: number
}

interface WebSocketData extends MyCommonData {
    type: 'WEBSOCKET'
    connection: WebSocketType
}

interface HttpStreamData extends MyCommonData {
    type: 'HTTP_STREAM';
    connection: HTTPStreamType;
}

type MyData = WebSocketData | HttpStreamData
```

Comment: So what if `MyData` is more complex and has types that are the same for every other property? Do I really have to define it twice?

Comment: Not at all! See my edit with a playground link at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Union types must have some common fields, in your case something like this would work

```
interface Header {
  key: string;
  val: string;
}

export interface WebSocketType {
  url: string;
}

export interface HTTPStreamType {
  url: string;
  method: 'get' | 'put';
  headers: Header[];
}

export class Stream { 

  constructor(
    public _type: 'WEBSOCKET' | 'HTTP_STREAM',
    public connection: WebSocketType  | HTTPStreamType
  ) { }
}




let newStream = new Stream('WEBSOCKET', { url: 'myurl' })
let newStream2 = new Stream(
  'HTTP_STREAM',
  { url: 'meaw', method: 'get', headers: [
    { key: 'someheader', val: 'somevalue' }
  ]
  })

if (newStream._type === 'WEBSOCKET') {
  if (newStream.connection.url.length > 0) {
    //do stuff
  }
}

if (newStream2._type === 'HTTP_STREAM') {
  if (newStream2.connection.url.length > 0) {
    //do stuff
  }
}
```